# Where to Put Neo4j Driver Instance in ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, neo4j, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.1

What is the ordinary way to establish connections to Neo4j DB in ASP.NET Core programming?

The code in Neo4j Language Guides (https://neo4j.com/developer/language-guides/) works fine for a simple console app, but it doesn't explain how to code in ASP.NET, so I just copy & pasted the code to MVC scaffold:

```
  public class TestController : Controller
  {
    public TestController()
    {
      _driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://localhost"));
    }
    private readonly IDriver _driver;
    public string Index()
    {
      using (var session = _driver.Session())
      {
        var greeting = session.WriteTransaction(tx =>
        {
          var result = tx.Run("CREATE (a:Greeting) " +
                              "SET a.message = $message " +
                              "RETURN a.message + ', from node ' + id(a)",
                       new { message });
          return result.Single()[0].As<string>();
        });
        return greeting;
      }
    }
  }
```

Works fine but calling GraphDratabase.Driver() for every request doesn't seem to make sense.

Shouldn't it be registered to services?
(AddSingleton() in Startup.cs?)

If so, how can I access the driver from the Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regestring it to services seems to be a good idea. You can do it like:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddSingleton(GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://localhost"));
    }
```

And then inject it to controllers:

```
public TestController(IDriver driver)
{
  _driver = driver;
}
```